# Why is this Javascript Ethash implementation returning a wrong hash result?

Tags: javascript, keccak, hash-algorithm, sha3, ethash

I'm trying to calculate the hash result for the "light" implementation of the Etash algorithm from [ethereum/ethash/js](https://github.com/ethereum/ethash) but I can't seem to get the correct result.

The expected result for comparison was calculated with both [ethereumj](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj) and [ethashjs](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/ethash#ethereumjsethash).

My code for the Javascript implementation:

```js
"use strict";

var ethash = require('./ethash');
var util = require('./util');

// init params
var ethashParams = ethash.defaultParams();
ethashParams.cacheSize = 16776896 //cachesize for epoc 0
ethashParams.dagSize = 1073739904 //fullsize for epoc 0

// create hasher
var seed = Buffer.alloc(32).fill(0); //epoc 0
var hasher = new ethash.Ethash(ethashParams, seed);

console.log('Ethash cache hash: ' + util.bytesToHexString(hasher.cacheDigest()));
// expected: 35ded12eecf2ce2e8da2e15c06d463aae9b84cb2530a00b932e4bbc484cde353 --> OK

        
var header = util.hexStringToBytes("c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470");
var nonce = util.hexStringToBytes("0000000000000000");

var hash = hasher.hash(header, nonce);
console.log("Ethash hash result: " + util.bytesToHexString(hash));
// expected: 89eaac0ac621d2bb2d1a62455119cb0d0a0883d554e748bab23c2066da080916 --> OK


header = util.hexStringToBytes("c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470");
nonce = util.hexStringToBytes("6c18bd55f3d77ab5");

hash = hasher.hash(header, nonce);
console.log("Ethash hash result: " + util.bytesToHexString(hash));
// expected: 0a9f8a9d1954c796b8bbafe0d443f1586c17ffe995070ea5a40436946c1bf2d7 --> NOT OK
```

Output:

```
$ node ./post.js 
Ethash cache hash: 35ded12eecf2ce2e8da2e15c06d463aae9b84cb2530a00b932e4bbc484cde353
Ethash hash result: 89eaac0ac621d2bb2d1a62455119cb0d0a0883d554e748bab23c2066da080916
Ethash hash result: 72d628f1bb9e7229f43c210824975d179f6b55da47ebe4655b4a55d677697391
```

So it seems that the cache is calculated correctly (the hash matches that of the other implementations). The hash result for a `nonce = '0x0000000000000000'` also matches, but a random other nonce calculates a result that does not match.
I assume this has something to do with the byte order of the nonce... any ideas how the nonce should be specified for the Javascript implementation to get a correct hash result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution is simple. I was correct assuming it has something to do with the byte order. Reversing the nonce before passing it to the hash-function did the trick:

```js
header = util.hexStringToBytes("c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470");
nonce = util.hexStringToBytes("6c18bd55f3d77ab5").reverse();

hash = hasher.hash(header, nonce);
console.log("Ethash hash result: " + util.bytesToHexString(hash));
// expected: 0a9f8a9d1954c796b8bbafe0d443f1586c17ffe995070ea5a40436946c1bf2d7
```